# Installing multiple Jenkins instances on same Windows machine caused issues

Tags: windows, jenkins, multiple-instances

I recently saw a blog, which suggested two instances of Jenkins can run on same Windows machine: [Two Guys Arguing, Pro Tips: Run Multiple Jenkins CI Servers on a Single Machine](https://twoguysarguing.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/pro-tips-run-multiple-jenkins-ci-servers-on-a-single-machine/).

But rather than deploying the `jenkins.war`, I actually installed another Jenkins on top of already installed Jenkins on my Windows machine, Which caused the previous Jenkins to stop.

Answer (score 4):

I made the mistake of installing Jenkins using standard Windows installation, instead of deploying the `war` like:

```
java -DJENKINS_HOME=/path/to/configs -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

which caused a change in Jenkins service's *Path to executable*. (Because during the 2nd Jenkins installation, I had chosen a different `JENKINS_HOME_1` path.)

To make another mistake, I tried to uninstall this second installation, but Windows Jenkins service was still having exe path as `JENKINS_HOME_1` (former `C:/Jenkins/jenkins.exe`).

To come out of this I had to change this *Path to executable* via:

- Command line:

  ```
  sc config Jenkins binPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.exe"
  ```

or

- Registry change:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Jenkins\ImagePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.exe"
  ```

I will try the `java -jar jenkins` options again though.

Answer (score 2):

Steps to install next jenkins instance:

1. You need make the full copy of working jenkins folder to second location.
   for example `D:\jenkins2`
2. next you need to edit inside this folder file jenkins.xml. Modify line

   ```
   <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8083 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
   ```

   and set value `--httpPort` to expected value.
3. run cmd.exe as Administrator
4. inside cmd run command: `sc.exe create JenkinsUpgrade binpath= "D:\jenkins2\jenkins.exe" displayname="Jenkins for Upgrade"`

   where `JenkinsUpgrade` is servicename and have to be unique,

   `binpath` contains desired path of new jenkins instance,

   `displayname` is the name displayed in services.

   This command creates a new instance of a jenkins server in a separated directory.

To uninstall this instance you can use command `sc delete JenkinsUpgrade`.